# plot gam results with original x values (not scaled and centred)

Tags: ggplot2, gam

I have a dataset that I am modeling with a gam. Because there are two continuous varaibles in the gam, I have centred and scaled these variables before adding them to the model.  Therefore, when I use the built-in features in gratia to show the results, the x values are not the same as the original scale.  I'd like to plot the results using the scale of the original data.

An example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(mgcv)
library(gratia)

set.seed(42)

df <- data.frame(
  doy  = sample.int(90, 300, replace = TRUE),
  year = sample(c(1980:2020), size = 300, replace = TRUE),
  site = c(rep("A", 150), rep("B", 80), rep("C", 70)),
  sex  = sample(c("F", "M"), size = 300, replace = TRUE),
  mass = rnorm(300, mean = 500, sd = 50)) %>%
  mutate(doy.s  = scale(doy, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE),
         year.s = scale(year, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE),
         across(c(sex, site), as.factor))

m1 <- gam(mass ~ 
            s(year.s, site, bs = "fs", by = sex, k = 5) +
            s(doy.s,  site, bs = "fs", by = sex, k = 5) +
            s(sex, bs = "re"),
          data = df, method = "REML", family = gaussian)

draw(m1)
```

[image]

**How do I re-plot the last two panels in this figure to show the relationship between year and mass with ggplot?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with `gratia::draw` automatically (unless I'm mistaken).*   But you can use `gratia::smooth_estimates` to get a dataframe which you can then do whatever you like with.

To answer your specific question: to re-plot the last two panels of the plot you provided, but with year unscaled, you can do the following

```
# Get a tibble of smooth estimates from the model
sm <- gratia::smooth_estimates(m1)

# Add a new column for the unscaled year
sm <- sm %>% mutate(year = mean(df$year) + (year.s * sd(df$year)))

# Plot the smooth s(year.s,site) for sex=F with year unscaled
pF <- sm %>% filter(smooth == "s(year.s,site):sexF" ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = est, color=site)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  labs(y = "Partial effect", title = "s(year.s,site)", subtitle = "By: sex; F")

# Plot the smooth s(year.s,site) for sex=M with year unscaled
pM <- sm %>% filter(smooth == "s(year.s,site):sexM" ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = est, color=site)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  labs(y = "Partial effect", title = "s(year.s,site)", subtitle = "By: sex; M")

library(patchwork) # use `patchwork` just for easy side-by-side plots
pF + pM
```

to get:

[image]

EDIT: If you also want to shift result on the y-axis as @GavinSimpson (who is the author and maintainer of gratia) mentioned, you can do this with `add_constant`, adding this code before plotting above:

```
sm <- sm %>%
    add_constant(coef(m1)["(Intercept)"]) %>% 
    transform_fun(inv_link(m1))
```

[You should also in general untransform the smooth by the inverse of the model's link function. In your case this is just the identity, so it is not necessary, but in general it would be. That's what the second step above is doing.]

In your example, this results in:

[image]

*As mentioned in the [custom-plotting vignette](https://gavinsimpson.github.io/gratia/articles/custom-plotting.html#building-your-own-plot-by-hand) for `gratia`, the goal of `draw` not to be fully customizable, but just to be useful default.  See there for recommendations about custom plots.

Comment: thanks! is there anyway to also have the y-axis back to the original scale?

Comment: The y-axis is on the original scale (you didn't scale `mass`).  In ggplot, you can shift the plot up by replacing `est` with `est + shift`, where `shift` is whatever you want it to be.  For instance, you could shift up by the intercept `m1$coefficients["(Intercept)"]`

Comment: the interpretation of the y-axis in the plots above represents the effect that `year` has on `mass` for a given site, by sex, controlling for the other terms, according to the GAM (it's very slight! try `draw(m1, scales = "fixed")` to see).

Comment: Adding confidence intervals, I think you'd see that the smooths in your example are not significantly different from constant (no significant effect).

Comment: +1 This is how I would do this. As the unscaled data never enter the model there's nothing gratia can do (easily) to facilitate the user passing along a set of alternative variables for use on the x-axis scales. As for your question above @tnt I would use the `add_constant()` and `transform_fun()` utilities to add the constant (intercept) term and apply the inverse of the link. Function `inv_link(model)` can get the required function for you.

Comment: @postylem thank-you for all your help with this question and breaking down the steps!  works perfectly, but more importantly, I understand what's going on.

Comment: @postylem, as I was working through this with my actual dataset, I realized I also needed to include the 'intercepts' for the by sex term.  Would that go in the add_constant() step before transform_fun()?

Comment: TBH I'm not sure I understand what you mean, @tnt, but if you want to shift the smooths before transforming, then yes, that should go in the add_constant() step, definitely before transforming (though if you're using an identity link it wouldn't matter).

Comment: That's what I figured.  I was refering to the terms generated by s(sex, bs = "re"), which don't really matter in this context as both sexes have the same mean, but could differ in other contexts.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, then. Of course you'd need to shift each plot by the (different) relevant value of the factor `sex`. If you're transforming the data all at once I'm not sure if you can do this with `add_constant` (since what you're adding is not, in fact, constant), but you could just do it manually with something like `sm %>% mutate(est = if_else(sex == "F", est + coef(m2)["s(sex).1"], est + coef(m2)["s(sex).2"]))`.  There's probably a cleaner way to do this, though.